# How to reload react native maps on click

Tags: google-maps, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I have developed one react native project where i have one functionality,In my map screen i have one button to show and hide user current location , for first time when i clicked on button it's showing userlocation and second time i clicked on that button it's  hide the user location , but after third time  it's not showing userlocation ,so can any one help me to here how to reload map so i will so again user location.

Library using : https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps

```
 constructor(props) {
                  super(props);
                  this.state = {
                      region: {
                          latitude: LATITUDE,
                          longitude: LONGITUDE,
                          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                        },
                        isShowLocation:false
                  };
            }
```

// Below method for show hide userlocation and set isShowLocation value to map "showsUserLocation={this.state.isShowLocation}" 
//  value is set properly but not able to reload the map

```
onbntshowUserLocationTapped(){

        if (this.state.isShowLocation == true)
        {
            this.setState({
                isShowLocation:false
            })
        }
        else{
            this.setState({
                isShowLocation:true
            })
        }
    }


   <MapView
    provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
    style={ styles.map }
    initialRegion={this.state.region}
    showsUserLocation={this.state.isShowLocation}
    followsUserLocation={true}
    >
    {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
        <Marker
          image={marker.pin}
          key={marker.key}
          coordinate={marker.coordinate}
          />
     ))}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can force react to re-render by changing the key value.

**key={this.state.forceRefresh}**

```
onbntshowUserLocationTapped(){

    if (this.state.isShowLocation == true)
    {
        this.setState({
            isShowLocation:false,
            forceRefresh: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        })
    }
    else{
        this.setState({
            isShowLocation:true,
            forceRefresh: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        })
    }
}


<MapView
    key={this.state.forceRefresh}
    provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
    style={ styles.map }
    initialRegion={this.state.region}
    showsUserLocation={this.state.isShowLocation}
    followsUserLocation={true}
>
{this.state.markers.map(marker => (
    <Marker
      image={marker.pin}
      key={marker.key}
      coordinate={marker.coordinate}
      />
 ))}
```